# Redux Toolkit - Code splitting/ Lazy loading redux modules/ Injecting reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Redux toolkit seems to be great. However, I am looking for options if we can inject the reducer dynamically something similar to [defining-an-injectreducer-function](https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting#defining-an-injectreducer-function)

**Use case:** I am planning to do route-based lazy loading using `React.lazy` and thinking of initializing the redux store at run time when a particular route/ feature becomes active.

In my setup, I am planning to Redux toolkit with `redux-observable` as I am coming from Angular & ngRx background and feel comfortable using `rxjs` and `redux-observable`.

So, any examples of using `redux-observable` as middleware with `redux-toolkit` will be of great help.

Looking forward to the suggestion.